# Find the interval of the real number and side-length $y$ such that the angle corresponding to it in this triangle is acute without the law of cosines.

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> The lengths of the sides of triangle RST are 3,4 and $\mathrm{y}$.

Find the interval of the real number and side-length $y$ corresponding to the side $RT$ such that the angle corresponding to it ($\angle RST$) in a triangle with two other sides three and four is acute without the law of cosines.

I was thinking we may draw a altitude to the side with length $y$, and then that divides into a section with length $a$ another section with length $b$ so that $a+b=y$.

Under the acute angle hypothesis I think $a^2+h^2<9,  (y-a)^2+h^2<16$, but I'm not sure how to prove this is the result of having a correspondence with an acute angle or whether this preposition is relevant, and I'm not sure what to draw.

Comment: Surely the Pythagorean Theorem should tell you something.

Comment: @TedShifrin It seems unclear to me that the Pythagorean Theorem, without the Law of Cosines, is conclusive.  You still have to prove (for example) that if $~\displaystyle y < \sqrt{3^2 + 4^2}~$ that the corresponding angle is $~< 90^\circ,~$ rather than $~> 90^\circ.~$  How is this shown without the Law of Cosines?

Comment: There are classical theorems (comparing angles and opposite sides) in Euclid. It’s impossible to know what is in your toolbox, but this should be.

Comment: See Propositions 24 and 25 in Euclid, Book I.

Comment: Proposition 18 is germane, as well. (We don’t need the law of sines to compare angles and opposite sides in a fixed triangle.)